# I am new to Gatling Tool. how do we coorelation and parametrization in gatling tool?

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new to Gatling Tool. 
how do we coorelation and parametrization in gatling tool. How csv data read in gattling.

Comment: this is all covered in the documentation https://gatling.io/docs/current/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example login with different users:

```
scenario("JustLogin").feed(csv("users.csv"))
.exec(http("Login").post("https://app.under.test.com/login")
  .header("Referer", "https://app.under.test.com/login")
  .formParam("username", "${Username}")
  .formParam("password", "${Password}")
)
```